# Remove a DIV from within it's child IFRAME (cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm working on a bookmarklet that loads Javascript from my server.  The JS adds a div with an embedded iframe (so I can pass/load content from my own domain).

I cannot figure out how to remove the DIV element, including the iframe, from within the iframe.  I can't reference `window.parent` because it is cross domain.  `window.postMessage` looks like it might be the right idea, but I haven't found sufficient documentation that helps me understand it.

I would very much like to have the iframe's *close* button within the iframe. Assistance is appreciated.

EDIT:
In my attempt to use window.postMessage, I have tried creating an event listener with the bookmarklet (ergo, on any domain):

```
var receiveMessage = function(event) {
    $("#iframecontainerdiv").remove();
    console.log (event);
    alert (event.origin);
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

And then within the iframe, I tried to trigger it:

```
$("#abort").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.close();
    window.postMessage("Hello, World!", "*");
});
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this right...

Comment: Have you seen this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: @Digital Plane - I added detail to the question that may help determine if I've been reading that page correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're posting the message to the wrong window. Maybe you should be using `window.top.postMessage` to post a message instructing the top window to remove the `iframe`.

So:

```
var receiveMessage = function(event) {
    if ("close-iframe" == event.data) {
        $("#iframecontainerdiv").remove();
    }
    console.log (event);
    alert (event.origin);
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

and:

```
$("#abort").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.top.postMessage("close-iframe", "*");
});
```

You could optionally test the origin of the message so that only messages from your domain result in the `iframe` being removed.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I was overlooking that I was posting the message to the iframe's window instead of the parent.  I'm still a little fuzzy on how the communication works, but I'm much closer to getting it now.  Thanks again for the solution.